# Right Auth with AngularJS, Django and external API service

Tags: python, django, angularjs, api

I'm developing my first AngularJS application with Django as backend.
My overall architecture is composed of:

- **Public API json-rpc server** (from which I must retrive data previous authentication process (the client send a user/password with a POST request, and then, the server response with a token string).
- **Django framework**, I use this because I need to have some models and MySQL db for additional data; *and because* the Public API server doesn't support CORS (is a old version) and I've created an API Proxy with one view of Django.
- **Angular JS App** that it served by Django.

Now, when the client first send user/password with AngularJS -> Django -> API server, the server respond with token, and henceforward the Client use token to make next requests.

My question is: **What's the right approach to retain the token on the client (AngularJS) (or on Django if required) after the user did login??**

Do you have any suggestion on my architecture?

Thanks in advance... and... sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending from your needs you should think about storing the token in the session storage in the local storage or in a cookie(in this case the cookie is used as a storage mechanism and not as an authentication mechanism).